# SXSSFWorkbook generates corrupted file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm using apache poi 5.2.0 to write large excel file (like 20k records or more). So i'm using SXSSFWorkbook because of low memory on server. The process works. I can open the file excel with ms excel and it works great.
The files will be uploaded on another system by browser. But when the system validates the file an error is thrown: "The file is corrupted...".
However, if I open the file after generation, and I save it, it works when I upload it on the external system.
I tried to do this thing: after generating the file, I re-take the file with a XSSFWorkbook without doing nothing (only the close action on XSSF instance).
In this way the file generated works on external system without any action after generation.

Unfortunately i can't do this, because with large excel the XSSF part causes the crash of job (because it load all excel file record on memory).
Any idea?

Edit: the file generated has a lower weight than the same file after I open and save it. So, something change in the file, but I don't know what. How can I see what is changed?

Comment: The only difference I see is that `SXSSFWorkbook` uses inline string values for cells instead of using a shared strings table. `XSSFWorkbook` as well as Excel itself never uses inline string values for cells but always uses a shared strings table. So try to construct your `SXSSFWorkbook` to also use shared strings table.

Comment: See constructor [public SXSSFWorkbook(XSSFWorkbook workbook, int rowAccessWindowSize, boolean compressTmpFiles, boolean useSharedStringsTable)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#SXSSFWorkbook-org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook-int-boolean-boolean-).

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter and ty for your response. I tried the constructor you suggested whit all possible configurations of the 2 booleans, but nothing has changed :(

Comment: Any update on this ? was any solution found ??